# Need sql related to grouping columns

Tags: sql, db2

I have data similar to this.

```
    ID        Age
    ------------
    101       60  
    102       40  
    102       40  
    103       25  
    103       35  
    104       28  
    104       28  
    104       28
```

Need the sql to out put only the rows which have same id but different age values.

```
    ID        Age
    ------------
    103       25  
    103       35
```

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: FYI. I'm using  DB2

Answer (score 0):

if you want only id:

```
 select id, count(distinct age) nb
 from yourtable
 group by id
 having count(distinct age)>1
```

if you want age too, join again your table

```
 with doubleage as (
 select id, count(distinct age) nb
 from yourtable
 group by id
 having count(distinct age)>1
 )
 select f1.* from yourtable f1 inner join doubleage f2 on f1.id=f2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
select * from yourtable f1
where exists
(
select * from yourtable f2
where f1.id=f2.id and f1.age<>f2.age
)
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
select * from yourtable f1
inner join lateral
(
     select count(*) nb from yourtable f2
     where f1.id=f2.id and f1.age<>f2.age
) f3 on 1=1
where f3.nb>0
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM F1 
WHERE ID In (
 SELECT F1.id
 FROM  F1
 GROUP BY F1.ID
 HAVING count(distinct F1.ID)>1)

1. This will give all the Id(s) and Age having duplicate records
2. Inner query will help you to get only the ID(s)

Comment: he want "with different age" ;)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly and you have only one table, this is what you're looking for:

```
select * from tablename group by ID where count(ID)>1
```

Output is the same:

```
ID        Age
------------
103       25  
103       35
```

Comment: I tried this                                                                                                     select count(*), id from  @table group by  id having count(id) > 1;      It is returning the ids with duplicate age values as well .     I just need id which have different age values.                                                                                                                             ID        Age
    ------------
    
    102       40  
    102       40  
    103       25  
    103       35  
    104       28  
    104       28  
    104       28

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
     [a].[id]
    ,[a].[age]     
FROM
    @tbl    AS  [a]
INNER JOIN
    @tbl    AS  [b] 
ON
        [a].[id]    =   [b].[id]
    AND [a].[age]   <>  [b].[age]
GROUP BY
     [a].[id]
    ,[a].[age];

P.S. if you have data like:
     (101, 60)  
    ,(102, 40)  
    ,(102, 40) 
    ,(103, 25)  
    ,(103, 35)
    ,(103, 35)
    ,(104, 28)  
    ,(104, 28)  
    ,(104, 28)
Result is:
    ,(103, 25)  
    ,(103, 35)
Not:
    ,(103, 25)  
    ,(103, 35)
    ,(103, 35)
Keep this in mind...
```

Comment: This is non-standard SQL. How do you know which DBMS Paul is using?

Comment: It is important to consider the algorithm, not the syntax

Comment: Thank you Juozas. Just alogirthm should be ok for me.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up. I may have the data like  this as well.                     ,     (103, 25)    
    ,(103, 35)
    ,(103, 35)

Comment: I have only single table. Your query can output 101 60

Comment: I have only single table. Your query can output  id which has one row   as well.  eg. (101, 60). I only need records which have rows with id repeating but different age values.

Comment: Using my query, it is impossible to return 101, 60, because condition "id same, age different" is false
Im working with single table too (@tbl)